How to force the unboundedness number to be uncountable?
Using Cohen forcing to add Cohen reals $c_\alpha$, $\alpha < \omega_1$, one can show that these form an unbounded family of said cardinality in the generic extension. As $\mathfrak{b} = \min \{ |\mathcal{U}| : \mathcal{U} \text{ is unbounded} \}$, it follows immediately that $\mathfrak{b} \leq \aleph_1$.
But how to prove that $\mathfrak{b} \geq \aleph_1$?

That is a theorem of $\sf ZFC$, so it is always true.
To see that, taking any countable family of functions, $f_n$, we can bound them by $f(n) = \max\{f_k(n) \mid k<n\}+1$.

I see, this is easier than I thought. Is it possible to adapt this argument to the case where $\aleph_2$-many Cohen reals are added and we wish to prove that $\mathfrak{b} = \aleph_2$? (It seems to me that such a simple definition of $f$ does not work because we may only specify $\aleph_0$-many of its values)

Edit: I mean a model where $\neg CH$ holds

No, you can't. Adding any uncountable number of Cohen reals brings the bounding number down to $\aleph_1$.
